# Remove line in bottom and top item Picker IOS on React native

Tags: react-native, picker

I used Picker to custom my screen:
[image]

You can see in my screen it have two line in bottom and top item slected.
How I can remove them?
Here is my code

```js
renderIOS() {
    let marginTop = isIOS ? 70 : 25;
    marginTop = this.state.isEdit ? 0 : marginTop;
    let color = this.props.theme.color;
    let serviceItems = this.state.listItem.map((s, i) => {
      return (
        <Picker.Item
          key={i}
          value={s}
          label={s}
          color={s == this.state.selected ? "white" : color}
        />
      );
    });
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: width,
          height: height - marginTop
        }}
      >
        <Picker
          style={{ position: "absolute", right: 10 }}
          itemStyle={{
            height: height - marginTop,
            fontSize: 35,
            width: 100
          }}
          selectedValue={this.state.selected}
          onValueChange={selected => this.setState({ selected })}
        >
          {serviceItems}
        </Picker>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: No, I haven't solution

Comment: could u plz put your whole component here ?  , I can not reproduce it properly

Comment: @Hoa.Tran Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya sory I can't do it. I hold the line in picker item.

Comment: Any solution for this